# Bash for loop syntax explanation

Tags: linux, bash

I am working in Bash shell, Linux OS. I have the following for loop:

```
for ((i=0;i<${#listModels[@]};i++))
do
var=${listVersion[$i]}
if [ ${!var} ]
then
    export MY_LIBRARY_PATH=$MY_LIBRARY_PATH:$ROOT_PATH/${listModels[$i]}/${listModels[$i]}_${!var}
else
    echo ">>>> No ${listModels[$i]} version! <<<<"
fi
done
```

Before this, I have the following in the script:

```
listModels=(model1
model2
model3)

listVersion=(MODEL1
MODEL2
MODEL3)
```

The concept is MODEL1,MODEL2 and MODEL3 keep changing every now and then, for eg it becomes MODEL1.1,MODEL2.2,.. And I expect the script to modify my path everytime the listVersion values change. But could anybody explain how exactly the for loop functions (especially [@] and [$i] stuff). I am new to Bash and I know only the basic commands. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in `man bash`, `${#array[@]}` returns the number of elements in the array. Similarly, `${array[$i]}` (better written as `${array[i]}`) returns the `$i`-th element of the array.

```
#! /bin/bash
array=( a b c )
echo Size: ${#array[@]}
echo First: ${array[0]}
echo Second: ${array[1]}
echo Last: ${array[-1]}  # Negative index counts from the right!
```

Comment: IIRC negative indexing is allowed from bash 4.2

Comment: The expression within the if statement `if [ ${!var} ]` means `i-th` element does not exist?